# Start loading div by clicking on a specific button

Tags: javascript

I'm using this `javascript` to show a hidden div for a loading message when I'm calculating in background:

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProgress() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = $('<div />');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            }, 200);
        }
        $('form').live("submit", function () { 
            ShowProgress();  
        });  
    </script>
```

As I understand the script is always running if a submit is fired

```
$('form').live("submit", function () { 
            ShowProgress();  
        });
```

How must I change the code to run only for a specific button is clicked?
I tried loading it when the button is clicked (commented out the `$('form').live("submit",...`)

```
protected void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> ShowProgress(); </script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", script);
    }
```

The loading div is showing but never stopping. What have I to change? Thanks

**Update**
Forgot the code in `if (!IsPostBack)`:

```
 string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=btnSubmit]').click(); });";
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
```

Comment: FYI: `live` has been deprecated in jQuery and removed in all current versions of it. Might be a good time to upgrade to a modern version.

Comment: @epascarello ok thanks, I will update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(){
  ShowProgress();
});
```

This method will run anytime the specific button is clicked (you obviously need to replace the `buttonId` in my code with the actual id of the button you made).

Comment: I my case I **have to** run postback first, then `ShowProgres()` with ` RegisterStartupScript`, 
so how can I remove with cient side javascript the modal background?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation describes [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/), the `live` method will apply to all events of the type submit. As suggested by other replies, you need to select just one element and use the `onclick` event, or check if the target of the event is your particular button.

I would go with the former, but depends on the behaviour you want.